# Testing database table creation with NUnit

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing, nunit

I'm new to using NUnit and have written a test to check for the existence of a database table. I have the below code that should check whether a new table named NewTable has been created in the database. It works correctly but I can't help feeling there's probably a better way of doing this. Thanks.

```
using(var conn = context.NewConnection()) {
    var tables = conn.GetSchema("Tables");
    foreach(System.Data.DataRow row in tables.Rows) {
        foreach(System.Data.DataColumn col in result.Columns) {
            if(row[col.ColumnName].ToString() == "NewTable") 
                Assert.Pass();
        }
    }
}

Assert.Fail("NewTable not created");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like this instead -

```
using(var conn = context.NewConnection()) {
    var table = conn.GetSchema("Tables");
    var tableNames = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                                            .Select(x => x["TABLE_NAME"].ToString())
                                            .ToArray();
    Assert.That(tableNames.Contains("NewTable"), Is.True);
}
```

Tests are usually structured in Setup-Act-Assert fashion. A good unit test is one that tests just one condition on an action.

Multiple asserts are practically unavoidable in certain cases, but having logic to decide when Assert should pass or fail isn't a good practice. The code under test should have the logic to branch, the test should only look at expected v/s actual results in a given scenario.

In this case, our setup is - we get the schema from the database, and get the list of column names.

Our logic (Act) is that certain column name must exist. So we write an assertion to ensure that.

In other cases, there is an action and a result, the assertion is on the result. In this case, it is more of testing a state, so there isn't an assertion on the result of an action.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think a simple explanation of why this is better ("only one assert", "better use of existing constructs", ...) could help.

Comment: wouldn't that check that there was a column returned by the GetSchema method named "NewTable"? I'm not sure that works. I want to check that a there is a table named "NewTable". I've just plugged that code in and the test now fails I'm afraid

Comment: @QuentinPradet - added a few lines on my thoughts around testing, hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer inspired me to a better solution than I had. I have submitted an edit to the code so that it solves the exact question asked. Thanks

Comment: @acqu13sce - I think you are right, the code might not work as it is. I didn't bother executing the getschema against a database. I'll try to make an edit that reflects something more real. Btw - I have included your edit.

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan in response to your thoughts on unit tests, the code I pasted is in fact just the Assert part. Setup and Act are performed before my code snippet is run. Setup connects to a database and Act runs a method that should create a new table, I wanted to assert that it did. Thanks again and for including the edit

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan Thank you, the answer is much clearer (and better) now!